# Duplicate type with name 'Dynamics.Ax.application.<My Class Name>' in assembly 'Dynamics.Ax.application,

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

I see following error when I compile CIL in Dynamics 2012 ax -

Duplicate type with name 'Dynamics.Ax.application.' in assembly 'Dynamics.Ax.application, version=6.0.947.280, culture...

I tried

1. Delete class  from AOT
2. Delete XppIL directory (c:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\InstanceName\bin)
3. Restart AOS
4. Run CIL compile

What else I can try ?

Comment: Did you try to compile the entire application?

Answer (score 10):

The following should resolve the problem:

- Full compile AX
- Stop the AOS
- Truncate the SysXPPAssembly table in SQL (the table is used to contain the assemblies and to share between multiple AOS instances)
- Delete the DLL and netmodule files in your AOS's bin\xppIL directory
- Restart the AOS
- Perform full CIL generation

Comment: The Review Nazies rejected my attempt to correct the table name; it should be [SysXppAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sysxppassembly.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked forme (this time).

1. Stop the AOS
2. Delete/Move XppIL directory (c:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\InstanceName\bin)
3. Restart AOS
4. Run Full CIL compile
5. Infolog displays list of errors returned by Full CIL.
6. Natively compile offending classes/projects, code corrections my be necessary.
7. Perform another Full CIL